# Pinterest Embed Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, pinterest

My ASP.NET application has a Pinterest embed button that does not grab the image for the preview and gives me an error message that looks like this, after I click on Pin It:

```
Parameter 'image_url' 
(value http:///Resources/Uploads/21622d3e-b865-49c4-bf22-155562ed2978.jpg) 
is not a valid URL format.
```

Can someone take a look at the code I use to generate the button and see if I did something wrong here?

```
PinterestEmbedButton.Text = String.Format("<a data-pin-config=\"none\" 
href=\"//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={0}&media={1}&description={2}\" 
data-pin-do=\"buttonPin\" >
<img src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png\" /></a>",
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), 
"Resources/Uploads/" + product.Images.FirstOrDefault().Image.LargeFileName, 
product.Name);
```

Edit:
The code generates a link that looks like this:

```
[http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.knueppels.com%2fCatalog%2fOnline-Catalog-Product.aspx%3fp%3d21536%26title%3dWax-Pottery-Bowl-And-Spheres&media=http%3A%2F%2F%2FResources%2FUploads%2F21622d3e-b865-49c4-bf22-155562ed2978.jpg&guid=_AigG3f1JKMF-0&description=Wax%20Pottery%20Bowl%20and%20Spheres]
```

[1](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.knueppels.com/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Product.aspx?p=21536&title=Wax-Pottery-Bowl-And-Spheres&media=http:///Resources/Uploads/21622d3e-b865-49c4-bf22-155562ed2978.jpg&guid=_AigG3f1JKMF-0&description=Wax%20Pottery%20Bowl%20and%20Spheres)

If you click on the `1` you will see that it does not pull an image and clicking on `Pin It` gives the error message I mentioned above.

I have tried changing the code to this:

```
PinterestEmbedButton.Text = String.Format("<a data-pin-config=\"none\" href=\"//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={0}&media={0}/{1}&description={2}\" data-pin-do=\"buttonPin\" ><img src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png\" /></a>", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), "Resources/Uploads/" + product.Images.FirstOrDefault().Image.LargeFileName, product.Name); but it still won't pull up an image and now I get the error 'Whoops! This is not a valid image.' Closer, though.
```

Comment: You need the full url to the image, including the domain (e.g. `http://www.knueppels.com/Resources/Uploads/21622d3e-b865-49c4-bf22-155562ed2978.jpg`) for the `media` parameter in the url.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I edited the original post to show that I added {0}/{1} to the `media` parameter in the url. This makes it `www.knueppels.com/Resources/Uploads` or whatever site I am running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Pin It button from an ASP.NET Literal to javascript for time's sake. I got the javascript from this post: http://www.brandaiddesignco.com/blog/add-a-custom-pinterest-pin-it-button-to-your-website/375/ and it seems to be working just fine. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into challenges like this with various Social Media buttons on Wordpress sites in the past (raw code not Wordpress plugins).  9 times out of 10 its a problem with the coding at the source.  A quick hack/fix is to grab the image from the source, upload it to your webserver, and reference the code to the image directory on your webserver as opposed to Pintrest's site.

Comment: That's a good idea, however this image is on our server. The code is referencing the uploads folder. I am stumped here. :/ I wonder if Pinterest has changed something recently, because this used to work just fine.

Comment: If they have developer resources or some point of contact for developers I'd leverage that.  Chances are they uploaded some code that broke some things behind the scenes and they don't even realize it.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll see what I can come up with from Pinterest. :)